# Unity with move gameobject line renderer

Tags: unity, c#, movement, mobile

I create DrawLine class, I want my character to follow the line I draw.

How do I move my character on draw line renderer ?

Thanks!

````
public class DrawLine : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject linePrefab;
    public GameObject currentLine;

    public LineRenderer lineRenderer;
    public EdgeCollider2D edgeCollider;
    public List<Vector2> fingerPositions;


    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            CreateLine();
        }
        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {
            Vector2 tempFingerPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
            if (Vector2.Distance(tempFingerPos, fingerPositions[fingerPositions.Count - 1]) > .1f)
            {
               UpdateLine(tempFingerPos);
            }

        }
    }

    void CreateLine()
    {
        currentLine = Instantiate(linePrefab, Vector3.zero, Quaternion.identity);
        lineRenderer = currentLine.GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
        edgeCollider = currentLine.GetComponent<EdgeCollider2D>();
        fingerPositions.Clear();
        fingerPositions.Add(Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition));
        fingerPositions.Add(Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition));

        lineRenderer.SetPosition(0, fingerPositions[0]);
        lineRenderer.SetPosition(1, fingerPositions[1]);

        edgeCollider.points = fingerPositions.ToArray();
    }



    void UpdateLine(Vector2 newFingerPos)
    {
        fingerPositions.Add(newFingerPos);
        lineRenderer.positionCount++;
        lineRenderer.SetPosition(lineRenderer.positionCount - 1, newFingerPos);
        edgeCollider.points = fingerPositions.ToArray();

    }

}


```
````

Comment: It looks like you already have code that accumulates a list of positions. Presumably you've tried moving your character toward the next position in that list, following [existing Q&A about moving a character through a list of waypoints in Unity](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/search?q=unity+waypoint)? How have you tried moving your character so far, and where specifically are you stuck?

Comment: @DMGregory I don't know how I moved character this position...

Comment: So you [searched out and followed some tutorials on moving a character in Unity](https://www.google.com/search?q=moving+to+waypoint+in+unity) to get a grasp of the basics, right? Please show us that you've made an effort to research this problem and attempt a solution, and clarify where you got stuck in that process.

Comment: @DMGregory Okey Thanks!